# In which order should I start learning theoretical physics on my own?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, education

I m very eager to start learning further physics but stuck at where to start!! I have a very good understanding upto +2 level and now I wish to go even further but dont know how or in which sequence I should study to get an awesome understanding of theoretical physics.
It will be of great help if anyone can help.

Comment: "upto +2 level"?

Comment: I don't know what "+2 level" means and I suspect I'm not alone.  Quantum field theory is very advanced stuff and I'd recommend avoiding it unless you already have a very solid understanding of basic quantum theory.

Comment: What up to +2 level is supposed to mean ? The tags give some idea of where you want to go, but it is totally unclear where you are unless you clarify that "+2 level".

Comment: +2 refers to the Indian high school system. @Aman, I would honestly start by just going through Resnik, Halliday and Walker's book and maybe starting Classical Mechanics by Kleppner or Kittel, since those are fairly common undergraduate textbooks.

Comment: If the OP is still in High School then really they should concentrate on that work and getting the grades required to study at university or similar.  There's no point in being distracted by advanced studies if makes you miss the required standard for university, if that's what they want.

Comment: I believe these sorts of questions will hardly be on-topic on Phys.SE, but 't Hooft has a site which is pretty much an answer to this question: https://www.goodtheorist.science/

Answer (score 1):

It's better to learn from the fundamental theories to the more advanced theories.

My suggestion:

PREPARATION WORK

1. Maths & Calculus (absolutely essential)
2. Newtonian Mechanics (i.e. Newton's Laws)
3. Thermal Physics (i.e. Ideal gas law)
4. Circular motion (i.e. centripetal acceleration)
5. Newtonian Gravitation (i.e. gravitational potention...)
6. Oscillations (e.g. SHM)
7. Waves (diffraction, refraction, interference...)
8. Electricity (DC+AC)
9. Magnetism (e.g. electromagnetic induction)

ACTUAL STUFF

Microscopic

10. Atomic physics (Binding energy...)
11. Partical physics (Bosons...)
12. Special relativity (E=mc^2)
13. General relativity (Cosmological constant...)

Macroscopic

14. Thermodynamics
15. Fluid dynamics
16. Cosmology

It might not work for you, but for me I find it quite coherent and effective way for studying physics.